# Keep two different versions of an entity in Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working on a Symfony4/Doctrine/MySQL project with the following requirement:

- Users can create entities (say posts) that are visible in the public frontend only after approval by an admin
- When a user edits his post after approval/publication, the changed post needs to be approved again before the changes will become visible in the frontend. But while approval is pending the old approved version of the post must remain visible in the frontend.

This means I have to keep two versions of every "Post" entity: the approved version for the frontend and the work-in-progress version for the backend.

In past projects with similar requirements I tried different approaches to this problem:

1. Using "Versionable behavior" (this was in the Symfony1/Propel days using sfPropelVersionableBehaviorPlugin). For display in the frontend, if an entity was not approved I had to fetch the previous versions until the latest approved version was found.
2. Using a second entity/database table "ApprovedPost" with the same field definition as the main "Post" entity. When a post is approved by the admin, it will be copied to the ApprovedPost table. The frontend operates on the ApprovedPost table only.

What is the current best practice to implement such a behavior?

Comment: Versioning is a highly complex issue, which means any answer you can get is opinionated and might not suit your needs. You could work with uniqueness-constraints on the database to ensure only one post-version is approved & published and then use a custom repository or maybe [filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html), which can be [configured easily in symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#shortened-configuration-syntax), to ensure only those are displayed by default on the frontend.

Comment: When it comes to displaying them in the backend you could temporarily disable the filters to also show the unapproved posts to the admins. Again this is rather vague to keep it less opinionated. Maybe you can start working on something and then come back to use, with concrete questions for your implementation.

Comment: @dbrumann, thanks for your comments. I'm currently experimenting with 3 different approaches to see which fits best:

Comment: 1. keep draft & published versions in one table using a composite primary key (id, approved) on the Post entity (where "approved" as a boolean in Doctrine), 2.  the same with normal auto-incremented id field and additional uniqe index (draft_id, approved), 3. two different entities for DraftPost and ApprovedPost. I have not decided yet which way to go and was hoping that there is a widely accepted "best practice" for this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Because I am chellenging this problem right now, I want to share my approach.
The entity is a request for something. Everytime something changes, the changes should be preserved.

**The approach:**

1. On every edit action, a new entity row is created.
2. The entity has an "approved" flag and a createdAt Date field.
3. A request has a nullable one-to-one self relation (to point to the root/parent entity).
4. A custom repository is used fo accessing the database.
5. The typical find and findAll methods are modified: they search for the most recent version (by the createdAt field) that is approved.
6. Search is done via custom SQL/DQL: `(WHERE id = ?1 OR WHERE parent-id = ?1) AND WHERE approved = true SORT BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`

More features can be added like enabled/disabled, deletion and so on ...

If you want to render the page server side and show the changed or old versions, I would recommend writing e.g. a Twig extension. You could implement different search functions in the repo and handle the representaion via the extension (sorting, referencing ...). 
I created an API, which is able to do both: return the newest version and return all versions (with or without root or newest), but I use the latter one in the frontend only if necessary.

Like dbrumann stated, this is a opinionated approach (I like custom repos, because I can create them type safe and I can decouple application from persistence logic).